# Training Mode Percents

Tags: wii-u, super-smash-bros-4

When practicing in training mode I may want to get to a certain percent, but it's very time consuming. Is there a way to go by like 50's or 100's or some sort of method that's faster other than going by 1's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In the Wii U version, there's no way to change the damage setting in Training mode any faster.**

However, in the 3DS version, it's possible to use multiple inputs (circle pad, d-pad, and touch screen) at the same time in order to cause the number to change faster, presumably proportional to the number of inputs. Not sure why this doesn't work in the Wii U version, but I suppose it must not have been intended.